# Entity Framework throw DbUpdateException if don't existing database value for foreign key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, fluent

I'm using to fluent framework for mapping between entities and database model.

For example, when I send a complete object for updated, but with the property [Guid? IdEnterpriseGroup] with error value [a GUID not existing in database] , the Entity Framework don't validate the foreign key before execute in database, and return a exception.

I going to describe my scenarios for someone help me.

My entity class Company to be below:

```
public class Company : DeletableCrudBase
{
    public Company()
    {
        IdCompany = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public virtual Guid? IdCompany { get; set; }

    public virtual string SocialName { get; set; }

    public virtual string FantasyName { get; set; }

    public virtual Guid? IdEnterpriseGroup { get; set;}

    public virtual EnterpriseGroup EnterpriseGroup { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<UserCompany> UserCompanies { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<CompanyAddress> CompanyAddresses { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<CompanyContact> CompanyContacts { get; set; }
}
```

My mapped class with fluent:

```
public class CompanyConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Company>
{
    public CompanyConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("ADM_COMPANY");

        HasKey(c => new { c.IdCompany });

        Property(c => c.IdCompany)
            .HasColumnName("ID_COMPANY");

        Property(c => c.IdEnterpriseGroup)
            .HasColumnName("ID_ENTERPRISE_GROUP")
                .IsRequired();

        Property(c => c.SocialName)
            .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(128)
                    .HasColumnName("SOCIAL_NAME");

        Property(c => c.FantasyName)
            .HasMaxLength(512)
                .HasColumnName("FANTASY_NAME");

        // Relationship
        HasMany(company => company.UserCompanies)
            .WithRequired(userCompany => userCompany.Company);

        HasMany(company => company.CompanyAddresses)
            .WithRequired(userCompany => userCompany.Company);

        HasMany(company => company.CompanyContacts)
           .WithRequired(userCompany => userCompany.Company);

        // Foreigners Keys
        HasRequired(x => x.EnterpriseGroup)
           .WithMany()
               .HasForeignKey(z => z.IdEnterpriseGroup);
    }
}
```

In my case, my problem to be about code:

```
// Foreigners Keys
HasRequired(x => x.EnterpriseGroup)
   .WithMany()
       .HasForeignKey(z => z.IdEnterpriseGroup);
```

I send about WS/Restful a object below. The property [IdEnterpriseGroup] is mapped foreignkey for ENTERPRISE_GROUP table. But when the object was send for Entity Framework, his don't validate entity foreign key.I sent a false key, don't existing.

We would like to create a unit test for validate the case fail for object or key not found.
One entity can has many properties foreign key, and we need validate all.

```
{
    "IdCompany": "ae776964-5547-49a3-bfc9-9d13a535c645",
    "SocialName": "Empresa 1",
    "FantasyName": "Empresa 1",
    "IdEnterpriseGroup": "8da84236-d352-4f3f-adee-b194a4b472cs",
    "EnterpriseGroup": null,
    "UserCompanies": null,
    "CompanyAddresses": null,
    "CompanyContacts": null
}
```

When the .Net Framework get exception, this throws a `SqlException`:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID_ENTERPRISE_GROUP', table 'BEECORE_1.1.dbo.ADM_COMPANY'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

I tried get the properties [HasForeignKey] mapped about the [CompanyConfiguration] but without success.

Someone can I help me with other solution please?

Comment: What is the issue? What do you mean by `I sent a false key, don't existing.`?

Comment: ... `IdEnterpriseGroup` is nullable, right? (i.e. a company does not need an enterprise group) ... otherwise maybe make the Guid non-nullable.

Comment: The problem is because the GUID [IdEnterpriseGroup] that was passed for object update not exists, is only a GUID created, generated for property set.
The property [IdEnterpriseGroup] is necessary and not null in database. In this case is necessary validate before execute update on.